# how can I detect and display all hardwares of a computer using java program?

Tags: java

Is there any way to detect hardwares plugged to a computer using java?For example,The program will be able to detect if a usb mouse is connected immidiately and show a message that an usb mouse is connected.

Comment: This sounds like a platform-dependent thing to me.  I doubt there's a solution in pure Java.

Comment: @David Thornley: Definitely platform-dependent. IIRC, Java programs don't have a mechanism to check for hardware - or its changes (was trying to get USB device connect notification, got discouraged at the thought of writing a JNI module for it).

Comment: Why are there two close votes?  It seems to me to be a perfectly legitimate question about programming.

Answer (score 2):

it is not possible with pure java. but you can use a native lib available on all important platforms, e.g. [SIGAR lib from hyperic hq](http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar)

Comment: I know the answer is too old, but an update: **This library hasn't been maintained for many years and is known to cause crashes.**

Answer (score 0):

This depends very much on the plattform your programm is running on.

in linux you can use the dbus api to register hardware changes

if you are only interestet in usb devices you should have a look at jusb (afaik there is even a windows port)